# How to finagle Pester to work with pipelined commands

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

This PowerShell function identifies files which do *not* contain a particular string:

```
function GetFilesLackingItem([string]$pattern)
{
    Get-ChildItem | ? { !( Select-String -pattern $pattern -path $_ ) }
}
```

I am attempting to write a Pester unit test by mocking Get-ChildItem and Select-String but ran into an issue. Here are two attempts that both fail in the same way. The first test uses Mock's `parameterFilter` to differentiate, whereas the second test adds logic to do this in the `mockCommand` itself.

```
Describe "Tests" {
    $fileList = "nameA", "nameB", "nameC", "nameD", "nameE" | % {
        [pscustomobject]@{ FullName = $_; }
    }
    $filter = '(B|D|E)$'
    Mock Get-ChildItem { return $fileList }

    It "reports files that did not return a match" {
        Mock Select-String { "matches found" }  -param { $Path -match $filter }
        Mock Select-String 

        $result = Get-ChildItem | ? { !(Select-String -pattern "any" -path $_) }

        $result[0].FullName | Should Be "nameA"
        $result[1].FullName | Should Be "nameC"
        $result.Count | Should Be 2
    }

    It "reports files that did not return a match" {
        Mock Select-String {
            if ($Path -match $filter) { "matches found" } else { "" }
            }

        $result = Get-ChildItem | ? { !(Select-String -pattern "any" -path $_ ) }

        $result[0].FullName | Should Be "nameA"
        $result[1].FullName | Should Be "nameC"
        $result.Count | Should Be 2
    }
}
```

If I modify the tests such that the Select-String `-path` parameter is `$_.FullName` instead of `$_` then both tests pass. But in real life (i.e. if I run the line without mocks) it works correctly with just `$_`. (It also works correctly with `$_.FullName`.)  So the real Select-String seems able to map FullName from an array of FileInfo objects for the Path parameter (though I could not find that there was a parameter alias to do that).

My question: is it possible to leave the original code as is, i.e. leave the Path parameter as `$_` on the line under test, and modify the Select-String mock instead to extract the FullName property? Trying for example, `$Path.FullName` in either mock does not work.

Comment: Does `Select-String` actually map `PSPath` property to `LiteralPath` parameter (alias `PSPath`, takes from pipeline by property name), not `FullName`? Can you try `PSPath` to `LiteralPath` instead of `FullName`?

Comment: @Roman: Not quite sure what you are suggesting. I have tried different combinations of properties in the $fileList instead of FullName, and also tried -LiteralPath vs -Path to Select-String, but have not found a combination that works.

Comment: I am not suggesting something specific. I just think that "Select-String seems able to map FullName from an array of FileInfo" is not quite correct because LiteralPath or PSPath is mapped, not FullName.

Answer (score 1):

since you are testing against a filesystem, i would suggest that instead of  mocking the `Get-ChildItem` command you use the `TestDrive` to fake a filesystem for these kinds of tests.

See http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/09/30/pester-mock-and-testdrive/ for more details on using `Testdrive:\`.